# ScrollView into ContentPage pushed Async doesnt work

Tags: ios, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, scrollview

i need your help. I actually begin with Xamarin.forms.
I have a HomePage : TabbedPage, which have 3 ContentPage.

One of those 3 pages is a ListView, which on item tapped, call an another Content Page with a ScrollView.

```
ListView.ItemTapped += async (o, e) =>
{
    var myList = (ListView)o;
    var newPage = (myList.SelectedItem as Object);
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page(Object));
    myList.SelectedItem = null; // de-select the row
};
```

I have a ScrollView on this new Page, but it doesnt work.

I copied the page and called it without Navigation.PushAsync, and the scroll WORKS.

I actually only use iOS Emulator.

Do you have any idea of the reason ?

I'm using xaml.

Thanks a lot. If you need more informations, tell me..!

There is my App.xaml.cs

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new HomePage();
    }
```

There is my HomePage :

```
public class HomePage : TabbedPage
{
    public HomePage()
    {
        var profilPage = new NavigationPage(new UserPage());
        profilPage.Title = "Profil";
        profilPage.Icon = "user.png";
        var gameListPage = new NavigationPage(new GameListPage());
        gameListPage.Title = "Jeux";
        gameListPage.Icon = "gamepad.png";
        Children.Add(profilPage);
        Children.Add(gameListPage);
     }
 }
```

And my homePage call GameListPage :

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="GameListView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate> 
            <TextCell Text="{Binding name}" />

          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

With event :

```
GameListView.ItemTapped += async (o, e) =>
        {
            var myList = (ListView)o;
            var game = (myList.SelectedItem as Game);
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new GamePage(game));
            //await DisplayAlert("Tapped", game.name, "OK");
            myList.SelectedItem = null; // de-select the row
        };
```

And the GamePage is here :

gamePage.xaml

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <RelativeLayout x:Name="RelativeLayout"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint =
          "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                 Property=Width,
                                 Factor=1,
                                 Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint =
          "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                 Property=Height,
                                 Factor=1,
                                 Constant=0}">
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="500">
                    </RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="500">
                    </RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="550">
                    </RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20">
                    </RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="300">
                    </RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="500">
                    </RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
                    </ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
                    </ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
                    </ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.Children>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="500"></BoxView>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="500"></BoxView>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="500"></BoxView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid.Children>
         </Grid>
          </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I putted this content actually to test the scroll. And, in one another contentPage, with the same content, i can scroll. Its just on this page, which is call with async Navigation.PushAsync...

Edited : SOLVED with a StackLayout with HeightRequest to 1500. My scroll work now.. temporary solved so.. Its not proper

Comment: you should post some code, or better, a little repo on github... Can you post "Page" code or xaml?

Comment: Yeah sure, i'll do it in a few time. I'll set my ListView Code, and my Page's XAML. Thanks

Comment: I edited it ! it's ok

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to set a `BackgroundColor` to your views like:

`ScrollView mainContainer = new ScrollView{
  BackgroundColor = Color.Red
};`

So you can double check that actually your view is being renderer to the `ContentPage` itself.

Also another issue can be that you don't have enough elements (`Label, Image, Entry, Button`... whatever: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/views/) on you ScrollView to actually scroll.

Set a test background color to your views and let us know what is actually the issue.

Also remember that the ScrollView has a `Content`property so you can add a layout to it. Example:

```
var stack = new StackLayout();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    stack.Children.Add(new Button { Text = "Button " + i });
}

MainPage = new ContentPage
{
    Content = new ScrollView { Content = stack }
};
```

Comment: I'm actually using Xaml for my view. I updated my post with the content of my files. Check it if you want.. ;)